# Save git output to a variable

Tags: git, bash

I have  `content= $(git diff --cached $line)` in my bash script.

[image]

But when I execute it, bash throws error

```
gqqnbig MINGW64 /c/Website/Lender (master)
$ ./hook.sh
Admin/Xpress/BusinessAccountTypeRole_Edit.aspx
diff: unknown option -- git
diff: Try 'diff --help' for more information.
```

Why doesn't `$(git diff --cached $line)` work, and how to fix it?

Comment: can you please paste actual code instead of screenshot?

Comment: Try [shellcheck](http://shellcheck.net). It automatically recognizes this and other problems.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It doesn't work because you put a space after the equals sign.

```
content= $(git diff --cached $line)
        ^
      there
```

That space means Bash sets the environment variable `content` to the empty string for the command specified by the rest of the line, instead of setting the shell variable `content` to the result of running the command.

To fix it, remove the space.

Comment: In case it's not clear you need to remove the space. E.g
`content=$(git diff --cached $line)`

Comment: Good point, thanks @Kildareflare! I've edited accordingly.